# What is the size of a geom at a given scale?

Tags: qgis, cartography, offset

I have a dataset with many overlapping grid cells. I would like to represent the cells in such a way that each grid cell is represented with one point. To avoid having the points overlapping each other I have chosen **centroid fill**. The centroid is a **simple marker**. I have figured that the best way of doing this is by adding a random offset to the centroid marker.

[image: From the simple marker user interface]

This will give a visualisation near to a hatched map as more overlapping grid cells will lead to more centroids filling the grid cell.

The expected format described in the expression string builder is:

> string of doubles 'x,y' or array of doubles [x, y]

This expression works fine:

```
to_string((rand(-20,20)/10))||','||to_string((rand(-20,20)/10))
```

[image]

Seeing how it works I now want a dynamic solution. How can I replace the grid cell size in millimeters with a calculated per grid cell (geom). Is there a way where I can calculate the represented size on the fly based on a fixed scale or even better - dynamically when I look at the map in layout mode?

Comment: So each of the squares visible in your image is actually a number of squares (indicated by the number of dots)? Why are there squares with no dots?

Comment: We have to retain attributes for each of the grid cells. They contain lists of data accumulated into each grid cell.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve -- as far as I can tell, it seems very peculiar: is the goal visualization? You're looking at raster data, why not maintain it? Values of overlapping grid cells can be combined into a new raster. This should obviate the issues you run into with this hacky approach.

Comment: Also already mentioned, I do not understand what you want to achieve, either. Plase be more clear. And it would help a lot if you could provide a sample of your data for inspection and testing purpose.

Comment: We're at looking at raster data, but rather a grid based on polygons. In layout mode the grid will have a relative size in centimeters (or inches for that matter). So I would like to calculate the extent of the cell in centimeter so that when I "seed" the random number from the cell centerpoint the random point will fall within the grid cell and not outside. Nor should it be clustering in the middle. It could perhaps work if a global variable from the layout is available for this calculation. Might work?